# Entity Framework confused about inheritance, returning subclasses instead of superclasses

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I added *Audit* versions of entities which are separate tables with few extra columns.

I defined them in EF like this

```
[Table("PERSON")]
class Person {...} // regular properties
[Table("PERSON_AUDIT")]
class PersonAudit : Person, IAudit { ... } // additional audit properties

public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<PersonAudit> PersonAudits { get; set; }
```

finding some unexpected behavior

```
    // querying table PERSON. this method should have nothing to do with PERSON_AUDIT
    public Person GetPerson(int personId)
    {
        using (var db = new Context())
        {

            db.Persons.Take(5).ToList(); // queries PERSON_AUDIT table! 

            db.Persons.Find(personId); // EXCEPTION: "sequence contains more than one element" because it queries PERSON_AUDIT table and returns multiple  

            db.Persons.Where(x => x.PersonId == personId).ToList(); // queries / returns multiple PersonAudit objects

        }
    }
```

so the wires are getting crossed somewhere, all queries are going out to PERSON_AUDIT instead of PERSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `PersonAudit` is a subclass of `Person`, querying the latter returns instances of `Person` including the former.

To avoid that, make both inherit a common `abstract` base, e.g. `PersonBase`.

Comment: querying the latter returns PersonAudit, not Person, which does not make sense

Comment: PersonAudit is a subclass, and points to a different table. I am just trying to query the table PERSON

Comment: this seems like a weird workaround. nowhere does microsoft recommend this pattern. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: notice in above documentation they have *public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }* which points to the table directly. they are not using AbstractPerson.

Comment: That shows exactly this pattern! Both `Instructor` and `Student` inherit a common `abstract` `Person` base.

Comment: yes you are right. but my case is a little different. i am trying to point sub classes to different tables. it looks like they are using the same table for all classes

Comment: ok , trying this out just to verify, let you know in a minute :)

Comment: i have to give it to you. that does seem to solve my issue but i still don't understand what makes it default to PersonAudit when im clearly querying the entity associated with Person

Comment: It does not default to `PersonAudit`. It's returning all `Person` including `PersonAudit`. Set a breakpoint on a line after `var answer = new PersonAudit() is Person` and observe the value.